# Display in hyperterminal analog and digital values from a potentiometer through micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, adc, potentiometer

This is the code that we have tried, it shows some digital values but not the analog values. Is there something wrong with the code? Can it be improved in some way?

```
#include "a library"

void setup (void)
{
     ADMUX =_BV(REFS0);
     ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN) | _BV(ADPS2) |_BV(ADPS1) |_BV(ADPS0);

}

unsigned int analogInput(char ch)
{

ch &= 0b00000111;
ADMUX |= ch;
ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC);
while (!(ADCSRA & _BV(ADIF)));
ADCSRA |= _BV(ADIF);
return(ADC);

}


int main (void)
{


    setup();
    SetupComputerConnection();
    unsigned int value;
          double analoguevalue;
    setup();

while(1)
{
    value=analogInput(0);
         analoguevalue=(value/1024)*5.0;
    printf("digital=%d analog=%.2lf\n", value);
}

}
```

Comment: like the code is supposed to show:
digital: "a value" and analog: "a value"
the analog values are supposed to correspond to the digital values

Comment: yes! that was a typo....i have corrected it now. However, it still does not work. Any other suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Update your question with some Hyperterminal output with the cursor of the potentiometer in different positions.

Comment: sure...just give me few minutes.

Comment: Also try `((double)value/1024)*5.0` and see how it goes.

Comment: Digital = 53 Analog = ?
Digital = 52 Analog = ?

its showing this

Comment: You might get a better response to this question if you ask it on the new [arduino.SE](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) beta site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
printf("digital=%d analog=%.2lf\n", value, analoguevalue);
```

`analoguevalue` was not displayed.

Also you should have used an interrupt to call the `printf` function only when the ADC register value is changed.

Comment: More precisely, you should set a flag in an interrupt and printf in main when the flag is set.

Comment: And also make sure that your flag variable is "volatile"...